# What is the correct way to invoke this Scala method on main?

Tags: scala

Me and my mates have to do a presentation on functional programming and we are trying to present standard deviation with FP, since they are beasts, they did the Scheme code for it. Meanwhile, I'm trying to convert that code into Scala since Sacla will be easier for introduction bcoz everyone in class is familiar with Java.

```
def soma(lista: List[Double]): Double={
 if(lista.isEmpty){
  return 0
 }else{
  return lista.head+soma(lista.tail)
 }
}
```

When I try to invoke it with soma(nameOfTheList), the program simply does nothing, it gives me no error message or output. I tried the main as follows:

```
    def main(args: Array[String]){
  val nums: List[Double] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
  println(soma(nums))
}
```

The idea is to use lists heavily but not use anything ready-made other than car/cdr or head/tail.

Comment: Can you please share the complete program? Where you have defined your method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have run the same method and it worked fine.

```
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    def soma(lista: List[Double]): Double={
      if(lista.isEmpty){
        return 0
      }else{
        return lista.head+soma(lista.tail)
      }
    }

    val nums: List[Double] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
    println(soma(nums))
  }
}
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: Hey, I just tried it like you defined it and it worked fine on scastie. scala-fiddle just won't give me an output at all, no matter how I write it. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

This is the code you want:

```
object TestApp extends App {
  def soma(lista: List[Double]): Double = {
    @annotation.tailrec
    def loop(list: List[Double], res: Double): Double =
      list match {
        case hd :: tail => loop(tail, res + hd)
        case _ => res
      }

    loop(lista, 0.0)
  }

  val nums: List[Double] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)

  println(soma(nums))
}
```

But I suggest learning a bit more Scala (and FP) before giving talks about it.

Comment: You are right that we should learn more about it before giving any talks on it. But this is for a class presentation for thursday, time is limited and I already fried enough braincells figuring out what x:xs is in Haskell.


Can I ask what "case _ => res" does?

Comment: That is a catch-all case. `_` matches any value of any type. I could instead have used `case Nil =>`, and this could be put before the other `case` and would have looked more like your original code.